# Add border to ctx.drawImage() within canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a demotivational meme generator and need to add a white border to the image added within the canvas

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight, 20, 20,300,300);
```

this is to add a border to the canvas

```
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineWidth = 2;

ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
```

how do I add a border to the image inside?

those are the coordinates:

```
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imgWidth,imgHeight, (canvas.width - newImgWidth) / 2, 20,newImgWidth,newImgHeight);

     newImgWidth,newImgHeight > 80% of imgWidth,imgHeight
```

[image: black outline within a white border around the image]

Comment: Fill in the whole canvas with your border color and then draw the image into the middle of the canvas. (Won't work on images with an alpha channel.)

Comment: I'm filling the canvas with black

Comment: OK well draw a white rectangle and then drop the image in the middle of that?

Comment: Shall I take it that what's happening currently is that you're only getting the border on two sides?

Comment: So first there is a black border...then a ticker white line...so two rectangles?

Comment: @Pointy how do I create two rectangles and fill them with different colors? I tried using `fillRect` but fills it with black

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ctx.strokeRect(1, 1, theCanvas.width - 2, theCanvas.height - 2);
```

You're using a line that's two pixels wide. You have to account for the thickness of the line in the rectangle you specify. You might expect the line thickness to all go towards the inside of the rectangle (and that would be convenient a lot of the time), but the thickness of the line is evenly split around both sides of the 0-thickness mathematical perimeter of the specified rectangle.

Comment: ok...this is adding up an inner border to the canvas...not to the image. should I align it with the image inside? what about the stroke color....I'm using `ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';` for the text inside...in this case I want it white

Comment: Sorry, yes, if that's where you want it. When I saw you were using `theCanvas.width` in your original code, I thought it was the border of the canvas you were shooting for. Is your goal like the white line in the image abobe, with a black gap around the image before your white border appears?

Comment: getting that effect is my goal

Comment: Well, your image is at 20, 20 with a width of 300x300. If you want a line that's 2-pixels wide with a 2-pixel gap, subtract 3 from the 20, 20 (two pixel gap plus half of the 2-pixel line thickness) and the double that 3 for the overall size of the border rectangle, giving you: ctx.strokeRect(17, 17, 306, 306);

Comment: I added the coordinates...it works for any picture on a canvas....Ijust would need to add the white border to the picture